# Architecture of data classes and business objects and viewer classes in Java (NetBeans Platform) RCP

Tags: java, architecture, netbeans

I have some experience with programming, but I am still quite an amateur. I went through many NB platform and IDE tutorials and read through some book, but it have not helped me, how to organise my RCP application with database (Derby embbed, not an external server).

What I have got?

1. **entity classes** (generated by NB IDE from database, for JPA) and JPA (using *EclipseLink*)
2. some view objects like **TopComponent**, Explorer etc. and **Nodes**
3. basic **real world "objects"**: books, chapters in book, characters in chapters

I guess, I should also use some *DAO class* for all three real world objects, which would create and send queries to database and return the data.
And of course, I would build some business objects for business logic. Probably "Books", "Chapters", "Characters", where for example instance of Chapter has attribute containing link to instance of Book, where the chapter is from.

But how to make basic operations like:

1. Getting collection of all books/characters or chapters of particular book for displaying in some view?
2. Basic CRUD operations with all business objects?
   and so on?

I mean, I can't call directly the DAO from my business object, for example from Chapters, to ask query for all characters, which have the FK in chapters table equal to the ID of this Chapters instance, can I? It would be too connected, my business logic and particular database system (in DAO).
And it makes no sense, to ask instance of Book to return all books. Should I make some static methods and probably attributes (collections) for this?
Or should I create some adapter class, which would call the particular DAO's methods and create from them particular business objects and return them?

So **my general questions** are:

- A) How to get collections of data? Where to maintain some collection of them?
- B) How to get individual data? When I edit some Character, for example its name, I change the business object attribute, but how do I get this change into database? Should the business object itself call the DAO somehow, or should I do in my view/controller not only update business object, but also the data object (probably via some adapter class)?

I would appreciate any help. I feel totally lost, but I can't create some app just so it works, I need a bit good design (it is kind of university work).

Answer (score 0):

consider using a framework like grails, or roo. these will get you crud for free. and they will give some structure (model-view-controller) for your app.

Comment: Thx, but I thought, GRails is for web apps, I have RCP desktop app. That is why I use Derby embbed for easily distribute my app.

But anyway, I would like to start programming something "easier" in a manner not needing to study many other things, I have spent months getting know NB platform. I just need to get some clue into basic design problem, how to connect loosely coupled business and data logic. I read Design patterns book, but still I need first "push" to start.

Comment: ok, consider http://griffon.codehaus.org/ - it's a groovy based rcp and will provide an mvc structure for you. also: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedded+Derby+DB+examples. try http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html for some mvc background